# how to find a user in a ParseUser object

Tags: android, parse-platform

Hi I was wondering why this code does not work. I am trying to query a ParseUser's username field to find a certain user but it keeps saying that it cant find it.

```
private void findUserName(String user) {
        // query the User database to find the passed in user
        ParseQuery query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.whereEqualTo("username", user);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                foundUser = (objects.size() != 0);
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is my method that calls it

```
if (!foundUser) {
    errorMessage.setText("Invalid user name");
}
```

foundUser is a field because I couldnt return it in the method...

Comment: How are you calling findUsername()? Are you sure the query has returned results before you read the value of foundUser?

Comment: im just calling findUsername before foundUser but my problem is that findUsername doesnt return results because I am not sure how to query a ParseUser object

Answer (score 15):

Parse treats User objects separate from Parse objects. You should use `List<ParseUser>` instead of `List<ParseObject>`. The Parse Android Guide provides an example https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#users-querying. 
Here is the Parse example with your where clause.

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
query.whereEqualTo("username", user);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
  public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
        // The query was successful.
    } else {
        // Something went wrong.
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Any idea how to then create a combined query that returns user objects? Beacuse ParseQuery.or will not combine a ParseUser query..

Answer (score 1):

İf you want to get current user this may be helpful;

```
String currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername();
```