# com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: invalid session token

Tags: android, parse-platform

Hello I am working on android app in which I am using parse cloud. I have signUp into the system then after I am trying to fetch data from parse.

But I am getting an exception everytime

> com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: invalid session token

```
String userName = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername();
ParseQuery<ParseObject> parseQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("users");
parseQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException parseException) {

    }
});
```

How we can resolve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Googling and Parse docs didn't give too much info about this exception, but There are few common mistakes I found. You should treat users as `ParseUser`, not `ParseObject`.

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
```

One more case: need to specify what to find in background. If it is `username`, so write:

```
parseQuery.whereEqualTo("username", userName);
```

And finally callback will contain `List` with `ParseUser`s, not `ParseObject`s

```
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
  public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
  }
});
```

I'm not sure exception will be gone, but I hope this answer will be useful anyways.

Some useful links: [doc with example](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#users-querying), [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16624745/how-to-find-a-user-in-a-parseuser-object), [Doc for class `ParseQuery` with examples](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html)

**UPDATE**

This is the official [doc](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide#sessions-handling-invalid-session-token-error) how to handle this error, also as I commented try to use `ParseUser.enableRevocableSessionInBackground()` after `Parse.initialize();` According to the SDK Documentation it is gonna update session token and only one case it could be invalid - `ParseObject` was removed.
Hope that helps.

Comment: where to specify class name there ?

Comment: Ah, I understood your question a little wrong, so you did right, just need to specify `parseQuery. whereEqualsTo("Field name in object", NameToSearch);` before you call `findInBackground`.

Comment: I don't want to add where clause condition.

Comment: Found one method to update session token, ty to add this line `ParseUser.enableRevocableSessionInBackground()` after `Parse.initialize();`

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I was trying to login while I already logged in.
Try to call `ParseUser.logout()`

Answer (score -1):

As Yurets said, you probably removed the session object. This can be solved quickly by uninstalling the app and then re-installing it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11020520)

Comment: @gio Why is it not an attempt to answer the question?

Comment: @gio I believe it does answer the question, as I've provided another approach to solving it (re-installing) which worked for me and didn't appear in the answer above.

Comment: it is solution only during developing process, but is not, for example, for app which was already published and have a lot of users

Comment: @gio fair enough. although the problem mainly occurs during development, in this case in particular.