# My error is : com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: invalid session token

Tags: android

I tried to work out the very basic cloud storage which follows below. Often i am getting an exception and in Logcat i am getting Unsuccessful while checking the overridden method.

```
package com.parse.starter;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.parse.ParseAnalytics;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.SaveCallback;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ParseObject score = new ParseObject("Score");
    score.put("username", "dinesh");
    score.put("score", 123);
    score.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
      @Override
      public void done(ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
          Log.i("info", "Successful");
        } else {
          Log.i("info", "Unsuccessful");
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    });

    ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent());
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: invalid session token](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29961642/com-parse-parserequestparserequestexception-invalid-session-token)

Comment: You know that the Parse cloud will be switched off in Jan. 2017?

Comment: @Harshad   This question belongs to store very basic information in Parse Cloud not to validate the credentials.All right

Comment: @ Robert   yes.But they are giving everything as an open source along with the developer tool where we can customize as per our client requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are initializing parse with credentials

```
Parse.enableLocalDatastore(getApplicationContext());
Parse.initialize(this, "YOUR_APP_ID", "YOUR_CLIENT_KEY");
ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
```